# Cannot Resolve Symbol error on a Class - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, class

New to stackoverflow so please bear with me.

I am getting a Cannot Resolve Symbol error on a class.

I have a class entitled CameraPhotoActivity (below):

```
package com.example.android.frapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CameraPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button uploadButton, showUploadDataButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_photo);

    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn);
    showUploadDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDataBtn);

 uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext().UploadInfo.class));
     }
 });

 showUploadDataButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     //     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext().ShowData.class));
     }
 });


}



}
```

It is the section below where I am getting the problem:

```
@Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext().UploadInfo.class));
     }
```

The error is on 'UploadInfo.class'.

It would indicate that I do not have a class called 'UploadInfo' but, as you will see below, I do:

```
package com.example.android.frapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class UploadInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

Button selectImageBtn, uploadButton;
ImageView user_image;
TextView title;
public static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
public static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Firebase mRoofRef;
private Uri mImageUri = null;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private StorageReference mStorage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.uploading_layout);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    selectImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImageBtn);
    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    user_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_image);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);

    // inititalise the progress bar
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadInfo.this);

    }
}
```

Below is the Manifest file where you will see I have added the 'UploadInfo' class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.frapp">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:name=".FireApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainLoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_screen"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.frapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateCaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_case"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NoteTakerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_note_taker"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".AddMainNotesActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CameraPhotoActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CameraVideoActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AudioActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".UploadInfo"></activity>
</application>
```

My build.gradle file is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.frapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

}



dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.2'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

// Firebase UI
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried the following:

1. Clean and Rebuild of Project
2. File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart
3. Sync Project with Grade Files
4. Closed project, closed Android Studio and imported the project from a backup
5. I even tried to delete the class I made and remade it via the options given on the line where the error is present but it does the same thing.

I hope I'm not missing something obvious but everything I've tried has been based on what I've seen from previous answers.

Please help

Comment: Post your logcat error message

Comment: All sorted now.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CameraPhotoActivity.this , UploadInfo.class));
```

Comment: that did it.  I knew it would be something simple.  I should have known this.  I feel stupid for asking the question now

Comment: Okay accept my answer by clicking a tick! Also the logic was because instead of a comma(,) you put a point(.). even getApplication would work. Okay accept the answer because you asked it only you can accept. StackOverflow style. @PAdams

Comment: So after all that it was actually because I put a point instead of a comma?  God damn it.  Now I feel even more stupid

Comment: Oooh not a problem at all, We all have those moments, I remember my first question in stackoverflow was I forgot the closing brace `}`. Hahahah

Comment: Lol well thanks again.  I've only wasted about an hour trying to fix it lol